# VBA to compare data to itself using multiple criteria and tag items with identifier

Tags: excel, vba, compare

[image]

Could anyone suggest a VBA solution to assist? I am attempting to compare a line of data (multiple criteria) against other lines within the same data set then tag it with an identifier to be used later. This is part of a larger VBA code project and I'm seeking a way to compare the data as efficiently as possible since the data could be over 10K lines. Everything I've tried so far with if/then arrays does not produce the desired result and compares the line to itself which is unnecessary. I'm not proficient with VBA so am possibly overlooking a simply solution.

Example code attempt and data attached. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Arr1 = WS.ListObjects("mockdata").DataBodyRange.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
    If Arr1(i, 1) = "AC" Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
            'concat doctype/reference/amount for comparison
            If Arr1(i, 1) & Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 3) = Arr1(j, 1) & Arr1(j, 4) & Arr1(j, 3) * -1 Then
                Arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
            ElseIf Arr1(i, 1) & Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 3) <> Arr1(j, 1) & Arr1(j, 4) & Arr1(j, 3) * -1 Then
                Arr1(i, 7) = "CFWD"
            End If
            Exit For
        Next j
    ElseIf Arr1(i, 1) = "XJ" Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
            If Arr1(j, 1) = "PY" Then
                For k = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
                    'concat reference/co for comparison
                    If Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
                    'if ref match but co does not
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) = Arr1(k, 4) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) = Arr1(k, 4) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co/Variance"
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    ElseIf Arr1(i, 1) = "PY" Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
            If Arr1(j, 1) = "XJ" Then
                For k = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
                    'concat reference/co for comparison
                    If Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
                    'if ref match but co does not
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) = Arr1(k, 4) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) = Arr1(k, 4) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co/Variance"
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Arr1, 1), 7).Value = Arr1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original answer will be preserved below but here is a working version for this data set.  There are a few things missing from your original code though: There is no check to generate a "CFWD" in an XJ type like your desired result shows so you'll need to work that out still.  Also in your AC you don't have a selection that will return a ZD result

```
Sub RUNME()

arr1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("mockdata").DataBodyRange.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
If arr1(i, 1) = "AC" Then
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        'concat doctype/reference/amount for comparison
        If arr1(i, 1) & arr1(i, 4) & arr1(i, 3) = arr1(j, 1) & arr1(j, 4) & arr1(j, 3) * -1 Then
            arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
        
        ElseIf arr1(i, 1) & arr1(i, 4) & arr1(i, 3) <> arr1(j, 1) & arr1(j, 4) & arr1(j, 3) * -1 Then
            arr1(i, 7) = "CFWD"
        End If
        Exit For
    Next j
ElseIf arr1(i, 1) = "XJ" Then
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(j, 1) = "PY" Then
            If j = i Then
                'skip this line we don't need to compare to itself
            Else
                If arr1(i, 4) & arr1(i, 5) = arr1(j, 4) & arr1(j, 5) Then
                    If arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) <> "0" Then
                        arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
                    ElseIf arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) = "0" Then
                        arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
                    End If
                ElseIf arr1(i, 4) = arr1(j, 4) Then
                    If arr1(i, 5) <> arr1(j, 5) Then
                        If arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) <> 0 Then
                            arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co"
                        ElseIf arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) = 0 Then
                            arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co/Variance"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
ElseIf arr1(i, 1) = "PY" Then
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(j, 1) = "XJ" Then
            If j = i Then
                'skip this line we don't need to compare to itself
            Else
                If arr1(i, 4) & arr1(i, 5) = arr1(j, 4) & arr1(j, 5) Then
                    If arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) <> "0" Then
                        arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
                    ElseIf arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) = "0" Then
                        arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
                    End If
                ElseIf arr1(i, 4) = arr1(j, 4) Then
                    If arr1(i, 5) <> arr1(j, 5) Then
                        If arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) <> 0 Then
                            arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co"
                        ElseIf arr1(i, 3) + arr1(j, 3) = 0 Then
                            arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co/Variance"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
End If
Next i
Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr1, 1), 7).Value = arr1
End Sub
```

Original Answer Below

Your logic has a flaw in it.

Anytime you're doing a set of comparisons (if statement here) and you're checking for a double true condition in addition to single true conditions you need to check your double true first, otherwise your single true will end the comparison and you'll get the results you're getting.

simplified if we have 2 columns:

x - True
y - True

if we did the following:

```
if x = True then
    b = Yes
elseif x = true and y = true
    b = YesYes
end if
```

the code will exit after the first check and never evaluate the elseif

You need to reorder your If statement accordingly.  I'm trying to get a working fix for you but I'm not really following your logic checks - if you can clarify this I can look at it again.

I'm also not sure that you need to go 3 for loops deep.

I did get it part way there with the following:

```
    ElseIf Arr1(i, 1) = "XJ" Then
    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
        If Arr1(j, 1) = "PY" Then
            For k = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
                'concat reference/co for comparison
                
                If Arr1(i, 4) = Arr1(k, 4) Then
                    If Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" And Arr1(1, 5) <> Arr1(k, 5) Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Cross Co/Variance"
                    End If
                ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) Then
                    If Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
                    ElseIf Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) = "0" Then
                        Arr1(i, 7) = "ZD"
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next j
```

Instead of doing 5 comparisons and getting a fail and doing another 5 comparisons break it up and do one, then do another smaller set. It might help speed up the whole thing

Edit: Looking at it more I don't see a case where you're current "Variance" condition will be met in your example dataset.

```
ElseIf Arr1(i, 4) & Arr1(i, 5) = Arr1(k, 4) & Arr1(k, 5) And Arr1(i, 3) + Arr1(k, 3) <> "0" Then
                   Arr1(i, 7) = "Variance"
```

Your desired row to get Variance is row 15 and 9

Arr1(9,4) & Arr1(9,5) would give "781498071220055"

Arr1(15,4) & Arr1(15,5) would give "781498071220008"

Comment: You are correct on the variance condition being met, I made an error with the mock data set (Arr1(15,5) should be 055. I'm reviewing your fix and it's very helpful; I'm going to see if i can leverage this. Ultimately the logic needs to identify items whose amounts net zero but only AC can net against AC, XJ can only net against PY and only if the Co numbers match; if they net but don't match, i need to ID that. Anything that doesn't net zero I need to ID that too. If this doesn't answer your question please advise.

Comment: That makes sense and kind of what I thought after tracking through it a bit more in depth. I believe you can get away with eliminating your K loop

Comment: I'm going to edit my original answer with code that works for this sample dataset.

Comment: I got your code working without the k loop after I corrected array references which hard coded the first row; presume that was an error. This is pretty quick to get through even on 10K lines and there don't appear to be any errors with the logic.Thank you very much Veegore you've been extremely helpful!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  I think there might be a more efficient way to do it but if this is working and not slow keep on using it